# Makefile path creation

Tags: c, makefile

I need to include a path for amount .c  which is located in a different location. How could I add that into the makefile?

```
expot PATH : G:\:$(PATH)

app.exe : zomato.o amount.o axisbank.o card.o cashondel.o end.o food.o hello.o kotak.o pass.o pnb.o sbi.o features.h
    gcc -o app.exe zomato.o amount.o axisbank.o card.o cashondel.o end.o food.o hello.o kotak.o pass.o pnb.o sbi.o

amount.o : amount.c features.h
    gcc -Wall $(PATH) -c amount.c

axisbank.o : axisbank.c features.h
    gcc -c axisbank.c

card.o : card.c features.h
    gcc -c card.c

cashondel.o : cashondel.c features.h
    gcc -c cashondel.c

end.o : end.c features.h
    gcc -c end.c

food.o : food.c features.h
    gcc -c food.c

hello.o : hello.c features.h
    gcc -c hello.c

kotak.o : kotak.c features.h
    gcc -c kotak.c

sbi.o : sbi.c features.h
    gcc -c sbi.c

pnb.o : pnb.c features.h
    gcc -c pnb.c

axisbank.o : axisbank.c features.h
    gcc -c axisbank.c

zomato.o :zomato.c features.h
    gcc -c zomato.c
```

Comment: `expot PATH : G:\:$(PATH)` ? that is so wrong. Typo on export, then you cannot concat windows paths with colons. If that's to illustrate, please edit to something more readable

Comment: I think you want `VPATH`

Comment: can you suggest how could i write makefile for that

Comment: how to write the file path in make file